# When do the characters of an integral domain form an algebraically independent subset?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Work over a fixed commutative ring $R$.

I'll just make sure we're all on the same page by quickly stating the relevant definitions:

> **Definition 0.** Given an $R$-algebra $X$ together with a subset $S$ thereof, define that $S$ is *linearly independent* iff the canonical morphism $A \leftarrow R\langle S \rangle$ is injective, where $R\langle S \rangle$ denotes the $R$-module freely generated by $S$.
>
> **Definition 1.** Given a commutative $R$-algebra $A$ together with a subset $S$ thereof, define that $S$ is *algebraically independent* iff the canonical morphism $A \leftarrow R[S]$ is injective, where $R[S]$ denotes the commutative $R$-algebra freely generated by $S$.
>
> **Definition 2.** Given a commutative $R$-algebra $A$, a *character* of $A$ is an $R$-algebra homomorphism $R \leftarrow A$. Write $\chi_A$ for the set of characters of $A$.

Okay. The following is well-known:

> **Proposition.** If $R$ is an integral domain, then for all $R$-algebras $A$, the set $\chi_A$ forms a linearly independent subset of the $R$-module of functions $R \leftarrow A$.

I'd like to know:

> **Question.** For which integral domains $R$ is it the case that for all $R$-algebras $A$, the set $\chi_A$ forms an algebraically independent subset of the $R$-algebra of all functions $R \leftarrow A$?

Partial answers are most welcome.

Comment: Check Artin's proof of the normal basis theorem in Jacobson's Basic Algebra.

Comment: Is it intended that your definition of a character essentially differs from the one used in the theory of fields ? Note that if $A,R$ are fields, the only algebra hom. $A \to R$ are embeddings. In particular there is no character $\mathbb{C}  \to \mathbb{R}$ while in field theory the absolute value $\mathbb{C}^\times \to \mathbb{R}^\times$ is considered a character.

Comment: @ToddLeason, that's fine. I'm using [warner's](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=nniSQ7ygxsEC&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=character+of+an+R-algebra&source=bl&ots=Ea1fmhASyo&sig=nJ0-yj_OfbAZwVfRn8oTfFXbD_0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz6OH6v-rLAhVHFZQKHfOGAZcQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=character%20of%20an%20R-algebra&f=false) definition. The motivating example for me is just $A = R[S],$ where $S$ is some set, in which case $\chi_A$ is canonically in bijection with the set of functions $R \leftarrow S$.

Comment: A condition on $R$ is: $R$ is infinite. For, if $R$ is finite, it's a field with, say, $q$ elements. From $r^q=r$ for all $r \in R$, it follows that $f^q - f =0$ for each function $f: A \to R$. Hence $f$ is an (integral) algebraic element in the function algebra $R^A$.